# Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in coideigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert multiple rows by one click. I have an add button called `add`. When I click add button it loads another row. In my case when, I submit a single row it saves to data base and gives an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: controllers/boq_controller.php

Line Number: 46
```

and this will occurs when I click add button also. Please help me to fix those problems.

**controller**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Boq_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('boq_model');

    }

public function index(){

    $this->load->view('admin_include/header');
    $this->load->view('project/boq');

}
public function create(){

                if ($_POST) 
    {
        $work_product_id=$this->input->post('work_product_id');
        $work_item_description=$this->input->post('work_item_description');
        $quentity=$this->input->post('quentity');
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $laboure_hrs=$this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
        $laboure_cost=$this->input->post('laboure_cost');
        $others=$this->input->post('others');
        $txtmultTotal=$this->input->post('txtmultTotal');
        $txtgrandTotal=$this->input->post('txtgrandTotal');
        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('work_product_id')); $i++)
        {
            $data[$i] = array(
                'work_product_id' => $work_product_id[$i],
                'work_item_description' => $work_item_description[$i],
                'quentity' => $quentity[$i],
                'rate' => $rate[$i],
                'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$i],
                'laboure_cost' => $laboure_cost[$i],
                'others' => $others[$i],
                'txtmultTotal' => $txtmultTotal[$i],
                'txtgrandTotal' => $txtgrandTotal[$i],
            );
        }
        $this->boq_model->create($data);
    }
   }
 }
```

**model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Boq_model extends CI_Controller{

function create($data) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('boq', $data);
}

}
?>
```

**view**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>


<div class="row clear_fix" style="width:1990px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div id="response"></div>

        <div class="well">



<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/create" method="POST">

        <table class="table" id="boq_tbl">
        <thead>

          <th>Work Product Id</th>
          <th>Work Item Description</th> 
          <th>Quentity</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Rate</th>
          <th>Laboure-Hrs</th>
          <th>Labour Cost</th> 
          <th>Others</th>
          <th>Total</th>

       <thead>

       <tbody>
    <tr class="txtMult">

        <td><input type="text" name="work_product_id" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="work_item_description" class="form-control" id="work_item_description" placeholder=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quentity" id="" class="form-control val1" /></td>
        <td><select style=" height: 33px; width: 102px; border-radius: 2px;" >
            <option value=""selected> </option>
            <option value="cube">cube</option>
            <option value="sq.ft">sq.ft</option>
            <option value="Cwts">Cwts</option>
            <option value="Gal" >Gal</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="form-control val2"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="laboure_hrs" id="" class="form-control val3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"name="laboure_cost" id="" class="form-control val4"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="others" class="form-control" id="others" placeholder=""></td>


        <td>
                <span class="multTotal">0.00</span><input type="text" id="txtmultTotal" name="txtmultTotal">
<!--            <input type="text" class="multTotal" placeholder="0.00">-->
        </td>
    </tr>

     </tbody>
       </table> 
<p align="right">
    Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span> <input type="text" id="txtgrandTotal" name="txtgrandTotal">
    <button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>

</p>

<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn btn-success" value="submit">
                </div>


</form>

    </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$("#insert-more").click(function () {
     $("#boq_tbl").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr class="txtMult">';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

$("#boq_tbl").on("keyup", ".txtMult input", multInputs);


function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
        var val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
        var val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
        var val4 = $('.val4', this).val();
         var total = (val1 * val2 ) + (val3 * val4);
        $('.multTotal',this).text(total);
        $('#txtmultTotal',this).val(total);
        mult += total;

    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
    $('#txtgrandTotal').val(mult);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take more care with your spelling and grammar. In English the first letter of each sentence needs to be capitalized. Also you have to insert a space after the end of each sentence. I fixed that for you.

Comment: Debug you code and see which value is not set properly.